# How to remove duplicated dicts in list1 and list2, and merge into a new list_all?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
list1 = [{'name': 'Tom', 'score':90}, {'name': 'Jack', 'score':86}, {'name': 'Lisa', 'score':81}, {'name': 'Bill', 'score':70}]

list2 = [{'name': 'Jack', 'score':86}, {'name': 'Bill', 'score':70}, {'name': 'Bob', 'score':48}]
```

**How to remove duplicated dicts in list1 and list2 (keep score's order), merge into a new list_all, and move the duplicated dicts into a list_new?**

```
list_all = [{'name': 'Tom', 'score':90}, {'name': 'Jack', 'score':86}, {'name': 'Lisa', 'score':81}, {'name': 'Bill', 'score':70}, {'name': 'Bob', 'score':48}]

list_new = [{'name': 'Jack', 'score':86}, {'name': 'Bill', 'score':70}]
```

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Duplicate of duplicate on how to remove duplicate? :)

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi - And after that, it's duplicates [all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down). :P